# How to share W10 wifi with Beaglebone black running Debian 9.5 through USB?

Tags: debian, network-interface

I am trying to share Windows-10 wifi with Beaglebone-Black running Debian 9.5, via USB and get a "temporary failure in name resolution".

The setup for this, usually consists of two steps (assuming Windows wifi-sharing already enabled)

1. sudo /sbin/route add default gw 192.168.7.1
2. echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> sudo /etc/resolv.conf

As I understand, the /etc/resolv.conf file is now replaced by a symbolic link to run/connman/resolv.conf. That is, when  the second command does not seem to append the echo-command to any existing file because there is no resolv.conf file in the /run/connman directory.

Should I set the nameserver-command elsewhere ?

Comment: I just solved the issue by making a new resolv.conf file, by
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
and adding "namespace 8.8.8.8" (without the quotes)